# Set of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the union/intersection equals...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to find examples of the following (if possible):

(i) A set of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the union equals $(0,1]$.

(ii) A set of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the intersection equals $(0,1]$.

(iii) A set of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the union equals $(0,1]$.

For (i), I found $$\bigcup_n (1/n, 1 - 1/n). $$ But I'm not really sure if this union equals $(0,1]$ or $(0,1)$ (how can you tell?).

For (ii) I found the open sets $ B_n = (0, 1 - 1/n)$. I think their intersection equals $(0,1]$, but not really sure either.

for (iii) I don't really know, so help is appreciated.

Comment: For (i), note that a union of opens is open.

Comment: Ah, I see. So for (i) there exists no example?

Comment: That's right, no example. The union of your intervals is $(0,1)$.

Comment: For (ii), did you intend to say $B_n = (0, 1 + 1/n) $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for (i) is not correct. First of all you should notice that the arbitrary union of open sets is open and therefore it can't be true. For your example you should ask yourself: Is $1$ in the union

$$ \bigcup_n(1/n,1-1/n) ?$$

Is it in any of the sets in the union?

Number (ii) is correct if you meant $(0,1+1/n)$, you should check that $(0,1]$ is in the intersection you suggested and nothing more can be in it.

For (iii) try the sets $[1/n,1]$ and check that this gives you what you are looking for.